# How to print unknown number of outcomes?

Tags: loops, scanf, printf

first time posting and also a beginner of C. My problem is how do I print an unkown number of results? Take this code for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a,b,c;
    b=0;

    printf("Enter the number of terms: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    for(b=0; b<=a; ++a)
    {
        printf("\n\nEnter the value of each term: ");
        scanf("%d",&c);
    }

printf("\n\n%d",c);

    return(0);
}
```

I want to print all the values entered in the end but Idk how to adjust it so that it will print 1,2,etc values.

P.S. How can I do this in a while loop as well using fprintf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use what is called an Array to store your data. You can think of an Array sort of like a filing cabinet with different drawers. Each drawer can store a value, and you can access that drawer by referencing its index.

You can learn all about arrays in C here:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-arrays/

Good luck!

Edit: Here is an example of fprintf:

```
/* fprintf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   FILE * pFile;
   int n;
   char name [100];

   pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","w");
   for (n=0 ; n<3 ; n++)
   {
     puts ("please, enter a name: ");
     gets (name);
     fprintf (pFile, "Name %d [%-10.10s]\n",n,name);
   }
   fclose (pFile);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment and your help. I don't know if I can use arrays yet since I haven't learned it yet in class but I'll still read up on the site you suggested. The thing is, I need to know for a project. If you know another way using fprintf that'll be grateful.

Comment: I haven't used fprintf personally, but it looks like it has to do with printing the contents of a FILE to the stream? I found an example online and added it to my post. Hopefully it helps.